# My second game object is working on background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two cheesbar in the game... once finished the other appears...and there is "eat button". when a mouse approaches to chees that button is being activated and make continueeating bool active. And I press and hold the button , cheese is being eaten and when cheese finished , second game object appears which means second cheese bar, somewhere, but start as a half cheesebar ...so even if it has SetActive(false); in the beginning , it is decreasing as if it was activated... how can I correct this.

thanks in advance.

```
void Start ()
{
    eatingcheese = maxcheese;
    eatingcheese2 = maxcheese2;
}

void Update ()
{
    cheesebar.fillAmount = eatingcheese / maxcheese;
    cheesebar2.fillAmount = eatingcheese2 / maxcheese2;

    if (continueeating)
    {
        eatingcheese--;
        eatingcheese2--;
        hungerscript.gettinghungery+=1.5f;
    }
    if (eatingcheese <=0)
    {
        cheesebar.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        cheesebar2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

}

public void eating()
{
    continueeating = true;
}

public void stopeating()
{
    continueeating = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that in the code

```
 if (continueeating)
{
    eatingcheese--;
    eatingcheese2--;
    hungerscript.gettinghungery+=1.5f;
}
```

You decrement eatingcheese2 whether or not cheesebar2 is active. You *could* check to see if the cheese is ready to be eaten and only proceed with decrementing eatingcheese2 if it is. You could use an integer to track which cheese you are currently eating to do that, and a switch statement to decrement either value based on that state. Or if you are sure you'll only ever have two cheeses, you can use a bool and an if statement.

Note that Update() is framerate dependent and you are dealing with eatingcheese numbers that will be very large (since they decrement every update while being eaten). I would suggest using a float from 1 to 0 representing whole and fully eaten cheese, and I would also recommend multiplying the amount eaten each step by Time.deltaTime so avoid the issue of scaling too fast and unpredictably.

Comment: thanks.. I added something like this if (cheesebar2.IsActive()) {
    eatingcheese2--;
    hungerscript.gettinghungery += 1.5f;
   }
now starts as an entire cheese but it is not decreasing when I press eat button :)

Comment: `if(cheesebar2.active)` is the way to check whether it is active. Take things one step at a time and use Debug.Log() to see whether the code inside the if statement is ever run.

Comment: UnityEngine.UI.Image' does not contain a definition for `active' and no extension method `active' of type.. .so I cant put "active" but isActive works for first image :/ but why not for the second?

Comment: Ah, my apologies I assumed cheesebar2 was a gameObject. Is your if(cheesebar2.IsActive()) statement nested within the if(continueeating) statement?

Comment: its ok ....I have just figured it out that I attached a cheescontroller to the first cheesbar .so , when first chees bar is not activated (finished) cheesecontroller is also deactivated because its the child of first  cheesbar:))  finally I have decided to add cheesescript to the mouse...now works fine :) thanks alot